# Java Jackson annotation for changing field

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have to call 3rd party API for currency exchange rate, but the JSON returned keep changing, if i request a `MYR` to `USD` conversion, it will return me: `{"MYR_USD":0.246731}`, so if i request for `KRW` to `USD`, it will return me `{"KRW_USD":0.000888}`.

I will have to map the returned result into pojo using `@JsonProperty`, is there any ways that works?

My current hard-coded workaround:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FreeCurrencyExchangeRate {

    @JsonProperty("MYR_USD")
    private double rate;

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"A":5}` is an object with field `A` having value `5`.
No `{"A":5}` is a `Map` with key/value pair `A=5`.

Both can be true, but since the value before `:` is dynamic (changing), it the second interpretation you need.

So don't ask for JSON to be converted to a POJO (`FreeCurrencyExchangeRate`).
Ask for it to be converted to a `Map`, then iterate that map.